# ()()()() after the title on the page

Tags: php, html

I have this code and it get something weird just after the title they are ()()()(). I been looking for this and I still don't have idea how to fix it. Thank you in advance.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>VER PRECIOS DE DESTINOS</title>
        <style>
            table,th,td
            { 
                font-family: Tahoma;
                border:1px solid black;
                border-collapse:collapse;
            }
            th,td
            {
                padding:5px;
            }
            th
            {
                text-align:left;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span style="font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 45.0px; font-weight: bold;  ">
            VER PRECIOS DE DESTINOS
        </span> 
        <table style="width:300px">
            <tr>
                <th>DESTINO</span</th>
                <th>PRECIO</th>     
            </tr>
            <tr><?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("Destinos") or die(mysql_error());
$order = "SELECT * FROM Destinos ORDER BY Destino";
$result = mysql_query($order);
while($data = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
     print "(<tr><td>$data[0]</td>)"; 
     print "(<td>$$data[1]</td>)";
    }
    ?>
        </table>
            </tr>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Likely something to do with: `print "(<tr><td>$data[0]</td>)"; print "(<td>$$data[1]</td>)";`

Comment: what is your character encoding?

Comment: [link](http://postimg.org/image/5v5bvo6i5/)

Comment: Your DB and table have the same name; are they actually the same name? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`  see if it yields anything.

Comment: This has all sorts of typos and syntax errors...

Comment: Remove the () from `print "(<tr><td>$data[0]</td>)"; 
     print "(<td>$$data[1]</td>)";` anything not inside the cells will render before the table

Comment: double `$` (dollar), and incorrect closure of `span`

Comment: Your last `</tr>` is after the `</table>`, by the way.

Comment: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: removing the () from print "(<tr><td>$data[0]</td>)"; worked Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Try the following, let me know if it helps ..

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("Destinos") or die(mysql_error());
$order = "SELECT * FROM Destinos ORDER BY Destino";
$result = mysql_query($order); 
?>



 <table style="width:300px">
        <tr>
            <th>DESTINO</span</th>
            <th>PRECIO</th>     
        </tr>
        <? while($data = mysql_fetch_row($result)){ ?>
        <tr>
            <td> <?=$data[0]?> </td>
            <td> <?=$data[1]?> </td>
        </tr> <?}?>
 </table>
```

If you need the brackets around the value try the following ..

```
 <table style="width:300px">
        <tr>
            <th>DESTINO</span</th>
            <th>PRECIO</th>     
        </tr>
        <? while($data = mysql_fetch_row($result)){ ?>
        <tr>
            <td> (<?=$data[0]?>) </td>
            <td> (<?=$data[1]?>) </td>
        </tr> <?}?>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that TABLE/TR/TH do *not* allow mixed content between the elements.

As such, the final HTML might look something like the following which is *invalid*:

```
<tr>(<td>..</td)(<td>..</td)(<td>..</td)</tr>
```

The browser does it's best to handle this situation and "moves" the ()()() parenthesis up, outside of the TABLE - as they are outside the TD elements. The parenthesis should probably just be omitted from the output or include inside the TD elements.

Answer (score 3):

When including content in a table that is outside the `tr/td` tags, that content is displayed outside of your table.

The problem is with the parens here:

```
 print "(<tr><td>$data[0]</td>)"; 
 print "(<td>$$data[1]</td>)";
```

Probably just remove them and you should be good.

[**See this Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9wcft/)

Comment: There's also a problem with the `</tr>`

Comment: Ya and @Phil is correct your table formatting is off. You have a closing `tr` *after* you close the table...

Answer (score 1):

### You don't have correct HTML structure

- Assuming `$data[0]` is 'foo', `print "(<tr><td>$data[0]</td>)";` will output `(<tr><td>foo</td>`. This is not valid HTML.
- You have a closing tag for table row (`</tr>`) after the closing tag of table (`</table>`) which not only is invalid HTML, but does not make sense.

### Do not mix up HTML structure with business logic

- Try separating your logic from structure
- Don't print the whole HTML with `print`s/`echo`s. PHP was designed to be a template creator (which is a sad affair on it's own, not suitable for an answer). So print just what needed to be printed dynamically.

  ```
  <body>
      <?php
          mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password") or die(mysql_error());
          mysql_select_db("Destinos") or die(mysql_error());
          $order = "SELECT * FROM Destinos ORDER BY Destino";
          $result = mysql_query($order);
      ?>
      <span style="font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 45.0px; font-weight: bold;  ">
          VER PRECIOS DE DESTINOS
      </span> 
      <table style="width:300px">
          <tr>
              <th>DESTINO</span</th>
              <th>PRECIO</th>     
          </tr>
          <?php
          while ($data = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
          ?>
              <tr>
              <td><?php echo $data[0]; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $data[1]; ?></td>
              </tr>
          ?php
          }
          ?>
      </table>
  </body>
  ```

  Now, it is clear that you are trying to create multiple rows inside a PHP `while` loop. Also `<td><?php echo $data[0]; ?></td>` can be clearly interpreted as: make a table cell, but it's content should be whatever the value of `$data[0]`.

### Other

- You have two `$` in this statement: `print "(<td>$$data[1]</td>)";`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.And let me know if it works.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>VER PRECIOS DE DESTINOS</title>
    <style>
        table,th,td
        { 
            font-family: Tahoma;
            border:1px solid black;
            border-collapse:collapse;
        }
        th,td
        {
            padding:5px;
        }
        th
        {
            text-align:left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <span style="font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 45.0px; font-weight: bold;  ">
        VER PRECIOS DE DESTINOS
    </span> 
    <table style="width:300px">
        <tr>
            <th>DESTINO</th>
            <th>PRECIO</th>     
        </tr>
        <tr><?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("Destinos") or die(mysql_error());
$order = "SELECT * FROM Destinos ORDER BY Destino";
$result = mysql_query($order);
while($data = mysql_fetch_row($result)){

?>
<tr><td><?php
echo $data[0]; ?> </td><td><?php
echo $data[1]; ?> </td></tr> <?php
}
?>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 <table style="width:300px">
        <tr>
            <th>DESTINO</span</th>
            <th>PRECIO</th>     
        </tr>
        <tr><?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("Destinos") or die(mysql_error());
$order = "SELECT * FROM Destinos ORDER BY Destino";
$result = mysql_query($order);
//while($data = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
//     print "(<tr><td>$data[0]</td>)"; 
//     print "(<td>$$data[1]</td>)";
//    }
?>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
    </table>
```

try comment out, i am suspecting semantic issue